# Java configure context root of web application

Tags: java, spring, properties, wicket, wildfly

I have a Java web application using Wicket 6, Spring 3.2 and WildFly 8.2.0. Right now i'm setting the context root of my web application in the `jboss-web.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/myCustomContextRoot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The `jboss-web.xml` file is compiled into the war. Now some clients want to change this context root to an empty context root. So i hace to recompile a version of my app per different context root. Is there a way to set the context root of my application from outside .war, programatically from a .properties file, or any other way for example in `standalone.xml` of WildFly 8.2.0?

Comment: Good question, I was also looking to change the context-root, but what I've have in hand is jboss-web.xml, if we can configure it in wildfly's settings like we're changing it in tomcat's server.xml, it would be much better..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the runtime name when deploying your web application. Suppose your WAR is called `myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war`. Using a runtime name of `foo.war`, the context root will be `/foo`.

Using a runtime name of `ROOT.war`, the context root will be `/`.

The runtime name can be set when deploying via the Web Console or via the CLI.

Comment: Such a simple solution, thx :) Since a few years ago we set the context-root in jboss-web.xml we forgot that the context root can be inherited from the war file name :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your Answer Harald Wellmann. It answers the question and pointed me into the right direction!

Some things I had to find out on my own and which may help others:

- the exact syntax in jboss-cli to specify a runtime-name is:

  deploy path_to_war_file --runtime-name=wantedName.war

  This leads to a context-root of /wantedName/ for the webapp.
- The runtime-name does not have any effect on the context-root, if the war file contains a jboss-web.xml in WEB-INF which in turn contains a context-root tag.

That is, if you want to control the context-root of your web-app in WildFly at deployment time, you must not specify any context-root in jboss-web.xml.

It is ok to have a jboss-web.xml without a context-root tag if you want to take advantage of the runtime-name to control the context-root.

I tested this on WildFly 9.0.1 and 9.0.2:

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem because I forgot to remove context-root from jboss-web.xml.